# Is it possible to implement two push_back(..) methods of std::vector in a single universal reference method?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I'm trying to implement `std::vector` all by myself for some exercising purposes. My question is about the `push_back(..)` methods. There are two overloads of this method as in the following.

```
void push_back(const value_type& value);
void push_back(value_type&& value);
```

At first, I implemented them in two different functions. For the former one, I choose to copy construct the new element with the given value. And for the latter one, I choose to move construct the new element with the given value. Here are the implementations of mine:

```
template<class T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(const value_type& value)
{
    if(size() == capacity())    // Size is about to surpass the capacity
        grow(nextPowerOf2(capacity()), true);   // Grow and copy the old content

    new(data + sz++) value_type(value); // Copy construct new element with the incoming one
}

template<class T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(value_type&& value)
{
    if(size() == capacity())    // Size is about to surpass the capacity
        grow(nextPowerOf2(capacity()), true);   // Grow and copy the old content

    new(data + sz++) value_type(std::move(value)); // Move construct new element with the incoming
}
```

After then, I realized that I could merge these two functions in a single method that takes a universal reference such as in the following code:

```
template<class T>
template<class U>
void Vector<T>::push_back(U&& value)
{
    if(size() == capacity())    // Size is about to surpass the capacity
        grow(nextPowerOf2(capacity()), true);   // Grow and copy the old content

    // Construct new element with the incoming
    new(data + sz++) value_type(std::forward<U>(value));
}
```

I think this single method handles all the things that I was trying to do with two different methods. Is there a thing that I'm missing? Will this operation bother me later? I don't seek backward compatibility, so you can omit it.

Comment: Your use of a template parameter `U` would allow the caller to pass in other types than just the `value_type`. Also, `std::forward<U&&>(value)` should be `std::forward<U>(value)`, see the examples in [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). And your use of `sz++` will increment `sz` even if the `value_type` constructor throws an exception

Comment: @RemyLebeau I fixed the reference issue. Post increment size can also be fixed, but it's not the main problem here. Thanks for warning me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version is not equivalent to the first one.

In the first you take an argument of type "reference to `T`", and in the second `U` can be of any type, not related to `T`.

So the second version is actually more an `emplace_back` than a `push_back`. It will take any value and try to construct an instance of `T` using that (though normally `emplace_back` takes a *pack* of arguments, for more flexibility).

You could restrict `U` to a type compatible with `T` using SFINAE, but then the code might become more complicated than just having two separate overloads.

```
template<class T>
template<class U, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::decay_t<U>, T>, int> = 0>
void Vector<T>::push_back(U&& value)
{
    // . . .
```

**stdlibc++** for example has two separate overloads for `vector::push_back`, but there `push_back(T&&)` simply [delegates](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/99dee82307f1e163e150c9c810452979994047ce/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L1202) to `emplace_back`. So maybe you could do the same.